# Apache, LocationMatch: match query string

Tags: apache, query-string, locationmatch

How can I match a query string using `LocationMatch` with apache?

```
<LocationMatch "/index.php\?a=b.*">
// ...
```

... won't work unfortunately.

Comment: LocationMatch requires a regular Expression, so you will have to at least escape the `/` and `?`. What pattern do you want to match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you can't include query strings in `Location`/`LocationMatch`.

From the [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#location):

> For all origin (non-proxy) requests, the URL to be matched is a URL-path of the form /path/. **No scheme, hostname, port, or query string may be included**. For proxy requests, the URL to be matched is of the form scheme://servername/path, and you must include the prefix.

Answer (score 4):

https://serverfault.com/questions/848320/can-locationmatch-regex-match-query-string-portion

Actually it's possible since Apache 2.4 (or less) using the tag as follow :

```
<LocationMatch "/test/upload.js">
        <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /query=test/">
                ..
                'Your directives'
                ..
       </If>
</LocationMatch>
```

In this configuration directives will be applied only in the case the URL is under the form "/test/upload.js" and contains the query "query=test".