# Git repository over http, Apache2 configuration not working

Tags: git, apache

My goal is to get anonymous read access (`git clone` / `git pull`) and authentified write access (`git push`) to a git bare repository via HTTP/HTTPS over an Apache2 web-server 2.4.29.

I try out the documented configuration (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend):

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
```

... in both variants ...

Variant 1) With module `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /git-receive-pack$
RewriteRule ^/git/ - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]

<LocationMatch "^/git/">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from env=AUTHREQUIRED
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldapserver:386
    Require user test
    Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```

Variant 2: Without module `mod_rewrite`:

```
<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldapserver:386
    Require user test
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/git/">
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

I am using debian package apache2 (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.14) on server side and git 2.29.2 on client side to test the configuration.

Both variants are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by uncomplete documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend.

For **Variant 1 (with module `mod_rewrite`)** it is needed to enable the rewrite engine. Adding `RewriteEngine On` solves the problem. With the proper `LogLevel` statement (commented out in the following example), you can observe the proper behavior in apache2 log file.

```
RewriteEngine On
#LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
```

For **Variant 2 (without module `rewrite_mod`)** the LocationMatch will not match in my case, because a `git pull` is done with a query string:

```
GET /git/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
```

The described LocationMatch is not able to check the query string of the request.
See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#location ...

> No scheme, hostname, port, or query string may be included.

A solution is to add `<If>...</If><Else>...</Else>` inside LocationMatch (see also [2019594](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019594/apache-locationmatch-match-query-string)). With the `CustomLog` statement it is possible to check in log file if LocationMatch is working as desired (see https://serverfault.com/questions/718234/how-to-check-if-locationmatch-regex-is-working).

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/location.log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b what:%{INDICATOR_VAR}e"

<LocationMatch "^/git/">
    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /service=git-receive-pack/">
         SetEnv INDICATOR_VAR "git push"
         AuthType Basic
         AuthName "Git Access"
         AuthBasicProvider ldap
         AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldapserver:386
         Require user test
         Allow from all
    </If>
    <Else>
         SetEnv INDICATOR_VAR "git pull"
         Require all granted
         Allow from all
    </Else>
</LocationMatch>
```